# Generate Dynamic Subdomains from URL parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, cpanel

I've looked at so many answers at this point I feel like I'm running in circles.

I have a multi-tenant site where each username should be a dynamic subdomain.  When a user goes to username.mysite.com the requested URI should actually be mysite.com/?shop=username.

What I've done:
1. Added a DNS record with the * wildcard pointing to the IP of my domain
2. Added a *.mysite.com subdomain via cPanel 
3. Added the below to htaccess.
4. Added code to my php file to catch the shop value.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php$
RewriteRule .? index.php?shop=%1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem I'm running into is that any subdomain entered gets rewritten to the domain root.  i.e. username.mysite.com -> mysite.com.

To be honest this is not my forte and I know just about enough to be dangerous here so any assistance would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you remove your .htaccess file and just try to access username.mysite.com/test.html. Are you still redirected to main domain? (juste to be sure if it's a server configuration problem or an actual htaccess problem)

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre - Thanks for the quick reply! I removed the htaccess file  and it still redirects so it doesn't seem to be a problem in the file.

Comment: In that case you might have a configuration problem in CPanel. Can you check that you do not have a redirection defined for this wildcard subdomain [Cpanel Subdomains Documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains)?